# Qual a função do app.listen no Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Recentemente iniciei meus estudos em NodeJS e Express. Pelo que eu andei lendo, app.listen, basicamente, é o que faz o servidor escutar as requisições vindas da porta definida.

Mas eu pude notar que ao executar uma aplicação em Express ela roda normalmente mesmo não havendo nenhuma declaração de escuta de porta. No caso, o express executa ela por baixo dos panos ou algo do tipo? Talvez eu esteja perguntando bobeira, mas não achei nada na internet que sanasse minha dúvida

Esse aqui é scaffold gerado pelo express. Como mostra o código, não tem nenhum listener, porém ele funciona e processa as requisições recebidas normalmente.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

/// catch 404 and forwarding to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

/// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "roda normalmente"? A função de uma aplicação Express é atender requisições HTTP. Se a aplicação não está escutando nenhuma porta, ela não tem como fazer isso.

Comment: Editei ali e adicionei o código. Dá uma olhada

Comment: Quando não tem nenhum listen a aplicação roda na porta padrão do node que e a 3000.

Comment: Então quando não se define, o node já possui um default, certo?

Comment: Dá uma olhada no seu package.json. Talvez tenha um script do npm rodando o servidor. Pra ser sincero, eu não manjo muito do express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `app.listen()` do Express inicia um socket UNIX e escuta as conexões em um caminho fornecido.

A função `app.listen(port, [hostname], [backlog], [callback])` do Express é a mesma `http.server.listen([port][, hostname][, backlog][, callback])` do Node. Segundo a documentação do Node, se nenhuma porta for passada como parâmetro, uma porta aleatória será utilizada.

[*Omit the port argument, or use a port value of 0, to have the operating system assign a random port, which can be retrieved by using `server.address().port` after the 'listening' event has been emitted.*](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback)

```
const express = require('express')()

express.listen(undefined, 'localhost');

express.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})
```

Vai iniciar um servidor sem uma porta específica. Por conta do Node (e não do Express), uma porta aleatória será definida.

Ou seja, é possível iniciar o Express sem especificar uma porta, mas não é possível iniciar o Express sem dizer onde escutar.

Nos meus testes, todas as vezes que tentei iniciar o Express sem o `app.listen` ele sai imediatamente.

Nesse caso, você pode verificar se a aplicação não está rodando em background já.

Pra verificar qual porta o Node está escutando:

`lsof -i | grep node`

Vai retornar algo parecido com isso:

`node      ...  TCP localhost:57466 (LISTEN)`

Comment: Mas a pergunta dele foi se o express inicia o server mesmo sem a chamada ao `app.listen()`. Ou entendi errado?

Comment: Editei pra tentar clarificar um pouco.

Comment: Ahh sim. Entendi, cara. Muito obrigado!!